# A non-GPL .NET library for non-linear Support Vector Regression?

Tags: .net, machine-learning

I am looking for a non-GPL library to use in a .NET project to perform a non-linear SVR. The most promising ones were Accord.NET and SVM.NET but both are unfortunately (for me) under a GPL license which makes them unfit for commercial use. The only other choice I have stumbled upon is LibSVMSharp but the library isn't documented and even the examples from the github page do not work.

My Google searches haven proven ineffective, is there anything out there comparable to Accord.NET and using less restrictive licenses?